# laravel 4 multiple root names

Tags: parameters, laravel-4, laravel-routing

how to define multiple names for a route

for example I want to have a route with names book or report and run same code for these routes

I can do this but it pass every string as route name :

```
/{route-name}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... not sure if by 'name' you mean in relevance to 'named routes' or the actual URI

**If URI**, just make 2 routes pointing to the same method:

```
Route::get('book', ['uses' => 'BooksController@index']);
Route::get('report', ['uses' => 'BooksController@index']);
```

**If you mean the literal Laravel terminology of** `named routes`, you can do the same, but name them (still pointing to the same method.)

```
Route::get('book', ['uses' => 'BooksController@index', 'as' => 'book']);
Route::get('report', ['uses' => 'BooksController@index', 'as' => 'report']);
```

Using this:

```
URL::route('book'); // will generate '/book'
URL::route('report'); // will generate '/report'
```

However, since each endpoint is pointing to the same method, both will result in the same code from your `BooksController` `index` being ran